# Using Rectangle and LineTo inside Windows Application

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to make an easy way to print X's and O's to the grid below without using multiple If-Else statements. I'm using a screen size of 575x620 for the application.

```
Rectangle(hdc, 5, 570, 550, 5);

Rectangle(hdc, 50, 50, 200, 200);
Rectangle(hdc, 200, 50, 350, 200);
Rectangle(hdc, 350, 50, 500, 200);

Rectangle(hdc, 50, 200, 200, 350);
Rectangle(hdc, 200, 200, 350, 350);
Rectangle(hdc, 350, 200, 500, 350);

Rectangle(hdc, 50, 350, 200, 500);
Rectangle(hdc, 200, 350, 350, 500);
Rectangle(hdc, 350, 350, 500, 500);


if( ttt.board[ 0 ][ 0 ] == 1 )
{
    MoveToEx(hdc, 50, 50, NULL);
    LineTo(hdc, 200, 200);
    MoveToEx(hdc, 200, 50, NULL);
    LineTo(hdc, 50, 200);
}
else
{
    Ellipse(hdc, 50, 50, 200, 200);
}
```

The code above is printing the first X and O to the first block and I would like to do the same for the remaining blocks without a ton of If-Else statements. Anyone have an idea or suggestions on how I can implement this? The data member is checking wither or not I clicked the box.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a `draw_cross` function, to which you pass one of the corners (or the center, if you prefer) of the square where it should draw. Likewise, a `draw_circle`. Then step through the board, and use those to draw the appropriate one in each square.